# Prove that every subset of a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove or give a counterexample of the following statement:

Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x = y\ \text{or}\ y=-x\}$

"Every subset of $A$ is closed".

I think the statement is true, however I do not see a clear way to prove this. Can anybody help me out? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $A$ itself is closed. If you for instance remove a point from it, the resulting set will be not closed anymore.

Comment: See it in another way: a set in which every subset is closed has necessarily the discrete topology, but this is not the case for $A$.

Comment: In fact $A$ is perfect, hence after removing a point the resulting set won't be closed.

Answer (score 2):

$A\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subset $B=\{(x,y)\in A \,/ x>0 \; and\; y>0 \}$. $(0,0)$ is a limit point of B which is not in B.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x = y\} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$
It is a subset of $A$ but it is not closed, since it does not contain its limit point $\{(0,0)\}$.